# OpenFiler cannot delete volume group

Tags: openfiler

I have deleted all the ingredients of a volume group even access options, but it still says that the Volume Group is in use. I tried to close everything including the OpenFiler itself but when I open it, it still says the volume is in use.

How can I overcome this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Go to the commandline on the Openfiler box or via Putty.
With the following command you can disable the volume group”

```
vgchange –a n <volume group name>
```

After disableing of the volume group, you can delete the whole volume with the following command:

```
vgremove <volume group name>
```

If you’re sure about this, you press y to continue.